# Schedule function to run at certain time within Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I am working on a c# project where I need to fire an event to happen at a certain time. I know that I can use Windows Task Scheduler, except I can't as it needs to be compatible with Mono running under Linux as well as Windows.

I know technically that Crontab could be used but that would involve having the bit of code I need to run in a separate program that Crontab could execute which is not what I want to have to do.

Is this something that is possible or is the best thing to have a thread running in a loop wich just checks the time every now and again and if it is the correct time, fire my code.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I beleive http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ can be used in Mono as well

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It can be set up as a one-shot event or as a recurring event.